# Как правильно обойти TreeView в WPF и вывести текст родительских и дочерних узлов?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Как правильно обойти TreeView в WPF и вывести текст родительских и дочерних узлов? Причем к каждому узлу добавлено ещё два дочерних узла Термины и Подразделы нужно получать текст каждого такого узла и текст узлов, которые находятся в узлах Термины и Подразделы.

- Item1
- Термины

  - Элемент списка1
  - Элемент списка2
- Подразделы

  - Item1.1
  - Термины

    - Элемент списка3
    - Элемент списка4
  - Подразделы

    - Item1.1.1
    - Термины

      - Элемент списка5
      - Элемент списка6
    - Подразделы

      - Item1.1.1.1

Код обхода:

```
foreach (TreeViewItem mPti in treeviewRazdel.Items)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(mPti.Header.ToString());

    if (mPti.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeViewItem pmxnt in mPti.Items)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(pmxnt.Header.ToString());

            if (pmxnt.Header.ToString() == "Термины")
            {
                foreach (TreeViewItem dmx in pmxnt.Items)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dmx.Header.ToString());
                }
            }

            if (pmxnt.Header.ToString() == "Подразделы")
            {
                foreach (TreeViewItem pmx in pmxnt.Items)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(pmx.Header.ToString());

                    foreach (TreeViewItem pxx in pmx.Items)
                    {
                        if (pxx.Header.ToString() == "Подразделы")
                        {
                            foreach (TreeViewItem phk in pxx.Items)
                            {
                                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(phk.Header.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код работает, но у меня TreeViewItemы подразделы и термины создаются по кнопке и для новых созданных обход не будет работать. Как создавать TreeViewItem динамически и во время обхода в цикле и получать его текст. Желательно, чтобы не приходилось создавать кучу новых foreach и TreeViewItem, а обход был сделан за пару циклов. Т.е. нужно отдельно получить item1 и его узлы, отдельно item1.1 и его узлы и т.д. до конца дерева что-то наподобия обхода в глубину.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, как вы будете использовать обходные данные и в каком виде (массив или список названий, классов). Согласитесь, что Ваш пример очень сырой, вложенность вообще только на 2 уровнях. А реально смотри мой ответ ниже. Совет: для начала нужно определиться со своим типом данных, или классом (вроде MyTreeItem).

Comment: Да сырой пример. Наверное буду использовать массив, класс я заранее не создавал. Но проблема основная не в этом, а в том как во время обхода мне распределеть, разделить и записать в разные XML файлы то что я получаю из дерева, разные термины, разделы и подрразделы в разные XML файлы с именами s1, s1-1, s1-1-1, s1-2 и т.д?

Answer (score 3):

Общая картина для твоей задачи: Создать простейшую рекурсивную функцию, заложить в нее необходимую логику. Например, так:

```
void FullObhod()
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem pmxnt in MyTreeView1.Items)
        Obhod(pmxnt);
}
void Obhod(TreeViewItem tw)
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem pmxnt in tw.Items)
       {
           //Анализ текущего элемента

           //в принципе сама рекурсия
           Obhod(pmxnt);
}
```

Если есть необходимость во время обхода еще и добавлять дополнительные элементы или еще чего, то могу помочь, пиши на semenvx27@yandex.ru

Comment: Написал вам на почту.